# I don't know how to write the format for A tuple in the function in order to put any date I want as a tuple. Thank you in advance

Tags: python, tuples

```py
def days_diff(a, b):
    A = tuple((), ()) 
    a = datetime.date(A[1][0],A[1][1],A[1][2])
    b = datetime.date(A[0][0],A[0][1],A[0][2])
        
    return abs (a-b).days
    
print(days_diff((1982, 4, 19), (1982, 4, 22)))  
# Expected output: 3 days
```

I want to have this output where you can put any dates as a tuple of integers. Currently  I have this error: `TypeError: tuple expected at most 1 arguments, got 2`.

Comment: Doesn't this code already work? Why are asking this question then?

Comment: No, it's not working, I have this error:  TypeError: tuple expected at most 1 arguments, got 2     I don't know what arguments I should put.

Comment: `tuple((), ())` is not the same as `((), ())`.  But once you have `A`, the tuples are not going to be valid inputs for `datetime.date`, and you are ignoring the arguments originally passed to `days_diff`.

Comment: Canyou accept an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
import datetime
def days_diff(a, b):
    A = tuple(a+b)
    a = datetime.date(A[0],A[1],A[2]) # main change
    b = datetime.date(A[3],A[4],A[5]) # main change
    
    return abs (a-b).days

print(days_diff((1982, 4, 19), (1982, 4, 22)))  #3 days
```

First you need to merge the tuples a and b to A and then simply use tuple indexing to get the desired value.

Comment: @Mina Please accept his answer if it helped you; this is so people know the issue is resolved and for people to find the correct answer more easily.

Answer (score 0):

The user will pass 2 tuples, so first we convert each tuple to date `datetime.date(*a)`, `datetime.date(*b)`. Now  we get difference by subtracting one from other, and take absolute value `np.abs(_ - _)` which is our output.
Note: `datetime.date(*a)` is equal to `datetime.date(a[0], a[1], a[2])`

```python
import datetime

def days_diff(a, b):
    return str(np.abs(datetime.date(*a) - datetime.date(*b)))

print(days_diff((1982, 4, 19), (1982, 4, 22)))
# 3 days, 0:00:00

print(days_diff((1982, 4, 19), (1983, 4, 22)))
# 368 days, 0:00:00

print(days_diff((1980, 9, 19), (1982, 4, 22)))
# 580 days, 0:00:00
```

Comment: Please explain how your code works; never just post code on its own.

Comment: The user will pass 2 tuples, so first we convert each tuple to date `datetime.date(*a)`, `datetime.date(*b)`. Now  we get difference by subtracting one from other, and take absolute value `np.abs(_ - _)` which is our output. 
Note: `datetime.date(*a)` is equal to `datetime.date(a[0], a[1], a[2])`